# Using link_to_remote inside of a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

how can I use link_to_remote inside of a controller?

I have already included ActionView::Helpers::JavaScriptHelper, but still get the error:

```
undefined method `content_tag'
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do. This is surely the wrong approach. link_to_remote makes no sense, since you are indeed at the "remote" (server).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to discover all of the helpers that need to be included to make it work. For instance, `content_tag` is part of `ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper`.

http://www.railsbrain.com/api/rails-2.2.2/doc/index.html?a=M002139&name=content_tag

It may be time to consider an alternative design.

Comment: I have moved the code to the model, but link_to_remote doesn't work without defining an explicit host.